# unable to use git push --force-with-lease from gitlab job (stale info with existing, up-to-date remote branch)

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm using `git push --force-with-lease` regularly, I think I know how it works ≈ if I don't have remote tracking branch pointing to same commit as the reference on remote machine push will be rejected (sorry for inaccurate description, I'm not git pro). Anyways it works every time for me. I saw `git push -f` in gitlab-ci.yaml and wanted to remove it, but I failed miserably. Does anyone see the problem? Why am I getting stale info??

---

EDIT 2: after investigating git log graphs produced in gitlab, the adding commit isn't problem, even the rebase is. So it starts just with detached work dir on some commit(no local branches whatsoever), then I checkout(explicitly with --track, local and remote name) master and somebranch so they are in-sync now, somebranch is rebased on top of origin/master. Everything is as it should be after these operations. Then git push --force-with-lease produces stale info.

---

After simplification and shotgun debugging I eventually ended in following `script:`  part, which clearly must work, only it doesn't. Maybe it's just gitlab runner issue, since even trivial stuff like `git log origin/master --pretty=oneline | head -n 10` does print data, but returns 1, for whichever reason. Anyways, HOW could following steps induce stale info??

```
#here we start in whichever start state, but probably after clone.  
- git config --global user.email whatever
- git config --global user.name whatever

#added in shotgun debugging session
- git remote prune origin

#so here we fetch both branches to have same remote refs as on origin
- git fetch origin master somebranch

#as I just cloned repo, I'm probably already on master, but just to be sure.
- git checkout master

#equally pointless, but just to be sure.
- git pull

#probably does not exist, but just to be sure
- git branch -D somebranch || true

#setup remote tracking branch
- git checkout --track -b  somebranch origin/somebranch || git checkout -b somebranch

#I just want to do this
- git rebase origin/master

#commit whatever
- touch whatever
- git add whatever
- git commit -m "Update whatever"

#push
- git push --force-with-lease https://${USER_NAME}:${PASSWORD}@<same as origin, using this just because have to specify user and pass here>
```

I will get stale info. Never on local machine, I cannot reproduce it and have no idea how is stale info induced. I'd get it if there would be conflicting commit meanwhile, but thee isn't, as there nothing new after this job runs. I checked git log and the rebase looks as expected.

EDIT: and some commit ids: My interpretation: everything is just fine. Rebase changed the commit id of top-level commit in *somebranch* (which is also the sole commit there), but that's fine since, we still have same  id one on server, and this is valid usecase how to force-push-with-lease and update commit on remote. Yet, it does not work.

```
#before anything
origin/master:::b26d16cccfe433b54312228b00578f693717532b
origin/somebranch:::1c63115fd659d2469705b27e1535912238565c1d


#before rebase
origin/master:::b26d16cccfe433b54312228b00578f693717532b
master:::b26d16cccfe433b54312228b00578f693717532b
origin/somebranch:::1c63115fd659d2469705b27e1535912238565c1d
somebranch:::1c63115fd659d2469705b27e1535912238565c1d


#after rebase
origin/master:::b26d16cccfe433b54312228b00578f693717532b
master:::b26d16cccfe433b54312228b00578f693717532b
origin/somebranch:::1c63115fd659d2469705b27e1535912238565c1d
somebranch:::f51b8b3094877634ad0add4693dda39ead1db54a


#after failed push
origin/master:::b26d16cccfe433b54312228b00578f693717532b
master:::b26d16cccfe433b54312228b00578f693717532b
origin/somebranch:::1c63115fd659d2469705b27e1535912238565c1d
somebranch:::a947d23dae87eaf57809247cd67a1e95142687f9
```

...and `fetch -all` at the end shows, that there is nothing new. How could I ended up in conflict if there is no conflict?

git 2.36.2

Comment: Most CI systems (and I think this includes GitLab's CI systems) use a shallow, single-branch clone by default, which won't get you what you need here. Consult the CI system documentation to see their recommended method to avoid that, or add`git remote set-branches origin "*" && git fetch --unshallow` before you attempt to make new commits and push them.

Comment: As a separate note, you'll also want to avoid putting secrets (passwords and/or tokens) into your CI yaml files, if at all possible. Again, consult the CI system documentation to find out how they support protecting such secrets.

Comment: @torek password should be fine, those are via env variables managed by CI. I tried to add your suggestion, but "fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense" — so it's complete repo. And I don't know what would be different, as I'm creating new track branches myself. But anyways, if I replace `--force-with-lease` with `--force` it works. Only `--force-with-lease` finds 'conflict' where it provably isn't.

Comment: OK, so it's not a single and/or shallow clone ... and the updated info you added seems to say that `--force-with-lease` should be working, so now it's a total mystery.

Comment: Thanks. If you have any other idea what to check, please ping me.